# How to display the elements stored in an integer arraylist?

Tags: java, random, arraylist

I've tried running this code for several times (re-opening eclipse IDE) but this doesn't change anything, the code simply won't run.. This a part of a PRNG.I've even tried to run the comment alone but all i get is[]`System.out.println(objprng2.clcg(2,10,50,44,54,67,6,6,4,6,2,5,5,4,5,5,4,5));`

```
package Firstage;
import java.util.*;

public class prng2 
{

    static List<Integer> seq = new ArrayList<>();

    public List<Integer> clcg(int mul_1,int seed_1,int inc_1,int mod_1,int mul_2,int seed_2,int inc_2,int mod_2,int mul_3,int seed_3,int inc_3,int mod_3,int mul_4,int seed_4,int inc_4,int mod_4,int newno,int more)
    {
        int a1=(4*mul_1)+1;
        int c1=(2*inc_1)-1;
        int m1=(int) Math.pow(2,(mod_1 +more));

        int a2=(4*mul_2)+1;
        int c2=(2*inc_2)-1;
        int m2=(int)Math.pow(2,(mod_2 +more));

        int a3=(4*mul_3)+1;
        int c3=(2*inc_3)-1;
        int m3=(int)Math.pow(2,(mod_3 +more));

        int a4=(4*mul_4)+1;
        int c4=(2*inc_4)-1;
        int m4=(int)Math.pow(2,(mod_4 +more));

        int X=0;

        int period=(((m1)-1)*((m2)-1)*((m3)-1)*((m4)-1))/8;
        int pc=0;
        int newlim=0;

        while (pc < period)
        {
            int i=1;
            int p=0;
            seed_1= ((a1 * seed_1)+c1)%m1;
            seed_2= ((a2 * seed_2)+c2)%m2;
            seed_3= ((a3 * seed_3)+c3)%m3;
            seed_4= ((a4 * seed_4)+c4)%m4;
            X=((seed_1)+(seed_2)+(seed_3)+(seed_4))% ((m1)-1);
            int R = X % 256;
           // System.out.println("for the "+i+" time R: "+R+" seq:"+seq.get(p) );
            seq.add(R);

            newlim= newlim + 1;
            if (newlim == newno)
               {
                break;
               }               
            else
                {
                pc=pc+1;
                }
       // i++;
       // p++;
        }
        return seq;
        }

    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        prng2 objprng2 = new prng2();
        objprng2.clcg(2,10,50,44,54,67,6,6,4,6,2,5,5,4,5,5,4,5);
        //System.out.println(objprng2.clcg(2,10,50,44,54,67,6,6,4,6,2,5,5,4,5,5,4,5));

            for(Integer element : seq) 
    {   
            System.out.print((element));
    } 
    }
    }
```

Comment: Please explain what this code should do.

Comment: what is not working? Do you want to get a pretty view of the list but it prints you a memory address?

Comment: Issue with the logic you are implementing. Also `'while (pc < period)'` this check always return false as value of period is negative

Comment: The code should give out an array of numbers which should be stored in the Array list "seq"

Comment: your `List<Integer> seq` is empty. Your program will run. By the way, what you are trying to achieve here ?

Comment: actually i'm trying to convert a piece of code from python to java

Comment: the implementation worked fine in python

Comment: `while (pc < period)` is always return false, period value is negative. so list is empty. Try to debug once, you will find the cause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

return is void because period is negative, because period is int and becomes too big.

The solution is to use big integers, then you have to change almost all your variables to BigInteger.

I made it. It seems better.

One advice: put some traces.

```
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.util.*;

public class prng2 
{

    static List<BigInteger> seq = new ArrayList<>();

    static final BigInteger one=BigInteger.valueOf(1);
    static final BigInteger two=BigInteger.valueOf(2);
    static final BigInteger BigFor=BigInteger.valueOf(4);

    public List<BigInteger> clcg(int mul_1,int seed_1,int inc_1,int mod_1,int mul_2,int seed_2,int inc_2,int mod_2,int mul_3,int seed_3,int inc_3,int mod_3,int mul_4,int seed_4,int inc_4,int mod_4,int newno,int more)
    {
        BigInteger BigSeed1=BigInteger.valueOf(seed_1);
        BigInteger BigSeed2=BigInteger.valueOf(seed_2);
        BigInteger BigSeed3=BigInteger.valueOf(seed_3);
        BigInteger BigSeed4=BigInteger.valueOf(seed_4);

        BigInteger a1=BigFor.multiply(BigInteger.valueOf(mul_1)).add(one);
        BigInteger c1=two.multiply(BigInteger.valueOf(inc_1)).subtract(one);
        BigInteger m1=two.pow(mod_1 +more);

        BigInteger a2=BigFor.multiply(BigInteger.valueOf(mul_2)).add(one);
        BigInteger c2=two.multiply(BigInteger.valueOf(inc_2)).subtract(one);
        BigInteger m2=two.pow(mod_2 +more);

        BigInteger a3=BigFor.multiply(BigInteger.valueOf(mul_3)).add(one);
        BigInteger c3=two.multiply(BigInteger.valueOf(inc_3)).subtract(one);
        BigInteger m3=two.pow(mod_3 +more);

        BigInteger a4=BigFor.multiply(BigInteger.valueOf(mul_4)).add(one);
        BigInteger c4=two.multiply(BigInteger.valueOf(inc_4)).subtract(one);
        BigInteger m4=two.pow(mod_4 +more);

        BigInteger X=BigInteger.valueOf(0);

        // TRACE HERE
        System.out.println("M1="+m1+" M2="+m2+" M3="+m3+" M4="+m4);

        BigInteger period=m1.subtract(one).multiply( m2.subtract(one)).multiply( m3.subtract(one)).multiply( m4.subtract(one)).divide(BigInteger.valueOf(8));        
        BigInteger pc=BigInteger.valueOf(0);
        int newlim=0;

        // TRACE HERE
        System.out.println("PC="+pc+" PERIOD="+period);

        // pc < period
        while (pc.compareTo(period)<0)
        {
            // TRACE HERE
            System.out.println("LOOP");
            System.out.println("PC="+pc+" PERIOD="+period);

            int i=1;
            int p=0;

            BigSeed1=a1.multiply(BigSeed1).add(c1).mod(m1);
            BigSeed2=a2.multiply(BigSeed2).add(c2).mod(m2);
            BigSeed3=a3.multiply(BigSeed3).add(c3).mod(m3);
            BigSeed4=a4.multiply(BigSeed4).add(c4).mod(m4);

            BigInteger m1minus1=m1.subtract(one);

            X=BigSeed1.add(BigSeed2).add(BigSeed3).add(BigSeed4).mod(m1minus1);

            BigInteger R=X.mod(BigInteger.valueOf(256));

            // System.out.println("for the "+i+" time R: "+R+" seq:"+seq.get(p) );
            seq.add(R);

            newlim= newlim + 1;
            if (newlim == newno)
               {
                break;
               }               
            else
                {
                pc=pc.add(one);
                }
       // i++;
       // p++;
        }
        return seq;
        }

    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        prng2 objprng2 = new prng2();
        objprng2.clcg(2,10,50,44,54,67,6,6,4,6,2,5,5,4,5,5,50,5);
        //System.out.println(objprng2.clcg(2,10,50,44,54,67,6,6,4,6,2,5,5,4,5,5,4,5));

        System.out.println("RESULTS:"+seq.size());

            for(BigInteger element : seq) 
            {   
            System.out.println((element));
            } 
    }
    }
```

Comment: tnxx but is how to convert the biginteger arraylist into integer array list

Comment: is this '//TRACE HERE' what you meant by traces . i'm new to programming

Comment: how to use .int value() please help me

Comment: BigInteger is a class (doc there:  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html)  . intValue() is a method in this class which return an int type with the same value (if in limits).

Comment: tnxx jst a line of code. is this correct `seq.add(R);`
`System.out.println("converted to INTEGER  converted and value    of R is " +R);`
`seqinteger.add(R.intValue());`

Comment: Better if you try yourself. It's the direct way to learn and get confirmation. Good luck  !